# Can a double pointer use both malloc/free and new/delete?

Tags: c++

I wonder if I had a class "Object", then I want to make an ObjectList - Object** p_obj. Then could I malloc/free for p_obj and new/delete for p_obj[i]?

Something like:

```
    p_obj = (Object**) malloc(sizeof(Object*) * count_obj)
    p_obj[0] = new Object();
```

and release them in destructor with delete and free;
If could, then what potential problems it may cause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Having both tags at once is almost always incorrect. As you are clearly using C++ (`new`), remove C tag.

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't. You could equally well do `Object o; p_obj = new Object*[1]; p_obj[0] = &o;` - "mixing" automatic and dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot thx, I have fixed that.

Comment: Paraphrasing Stroustrup: If your code has a `delete` or `delete[]`, you probably have a bug. If it has a naked `new` or `new[]`, it should have a `delete` or `delete[]`, see first sentence. So just use containers and automatic objects, and smart pointers if needed (rare).

Comment: So tl;dr: Use `std::vector<Object>`, forget about `new[]` and `malloc`. Both will yield poor code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is technically not "wrong", it definitely goes against the C++ paradigm.

The biggest problem you'll end up with is the confusion you'll cause yourself and anyone else who has to maintain the code.

As a general rule, use `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free` in C++. And for bonus points, use smart pointers and never deal directly with object allocation or de-allocation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is legal, but why would you want to do that? Use `new` for everything.

> what potential problems it may cause?

Accidently using wrong deallocation. It is not easy to *just* get dynamic memory handling done properly. If you would increase complexiti with that...

Comment: A possible reason to use `malloc` in c++ is when you want to to have option to re-size the allocation (using `realloc`) without copy of the elements.

Comment: @SHR Yes u r right, I want to re-size if the list is full. But it's tedious to still using malloc for p_item[i]. That's why this question comes out.